# How to transfer object from one class to another class - JAVA

Tags: java, jfreechart, personality-insights

I am trying to display the value of percentage in a pie chart, for that I have the percentage value in the `Personality`class and the `Chart` Class is where I need to show it. My code structure is below:

**Personality.JAVA**

```
   Tree C = gson.fromJson(profile.toString(), Tree.class);  

                Tree.SubTree t = C.getTree(); 
                ArrayList<Children> mc = t.getChildren();
                Children c1 = mc.get(0);

                ArrayList<Children1> c2 = c1.getChildren();
                Children1 obj1 = c2.get(0);

                private Children1 obj1; //ERROR-ILEGAL START OF EXPRESSION 


                public Children1 getObj1(){
                return this.obj1;
               } 

         /**       ArrayList<child2> c3 = obj1.children;
                child2 obj2 = c3.get(0);

                ArrayList<child3> c4 = obj2.children;
                child3 obj3 = c4.get(0);  **/


                System.out.println(obj1.getPercentage()); //ERROR - IDENTIFIER EXPECTED
```

**Children1.JAVA**

```
   public class Children1 {
     private String category;
     private String id;
     private String name;
     private double percentage;
     private double sampling_error;
     private ArrayList<Children2> children;

    public Double getPercentage() {
     return percentage;
   }
/**
* 
* @param percentage
* The percentage
*/
    public void setPercentage(Double percentage) {
    this.percentage = percentage;
    }
}
```

**Tree.JAVA(Not sure if this class is necessary but here it is)**

```
public class Tree {
    private SubTree tree;  
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID: " + id + "\n" + "Name: "+ "\n" + tree+ "\n" ;
    }  
    class SubTree{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Children> children; //Gets Arraylist from Class - Children


    public ArrayList<Children> getChildren() {
    return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(ArrayList<Children> children) {
    this.children = children;
    }     
    }

   public SubTree getTree() {
     return tree;
   }

    public void setTree() {
    this.tree = tree;
    }

}
```

**CHART CLASS**

```
private PieDataset createDataset(){
   Personality m = new Personality();
  // Personality.class = Personality();
    DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
    result.setValue("Value1",m.obj1 ); //attempted to get obj1 from Persoanlity Class
    result.setValue("Linux", 10);
    result.setValue("Mac", 25);
    return result;
}
```

So overall program is - get normal paragraph convert to json then to parse to java after using java values produce graph. So in this case get percentage value `obj1` to show in `Chart class`.

Hope you guys understood the question and thankyou for your time :)

Comment: I'm with @Luminous_Dev -- you need to transfer data -- so what's preventing you from doing so, perhaps via a constructor or method parameter? And consider condensing your code into a viable [mcve] / [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: In the Chart class it says cannot find symbol when hovering over the m.obj1 part .

Comment: Why are you accessing fields directly? Why not use public getter methods to control access?

Comment: If you give us the Personality class codes we can may see where it is causing.

Comment: @Luminous_Dev: but nor should it be public.

Comment: Java is not an acronym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the `Children1` object visible from the `Personality` class.  At the moment it looks like `obj1` is just a local variable and its scope is only visible to that local method

If in Personality, you have a field `Children1 obj1` then this could be set by the local method or constructor.  If the scope of `Children1 obj1` was public OR preferably it had a getter method, then you could read it from the `Chart class` assuming that the `Children1 obj1` is created in the constructor i.e. `Personality m = new Personality();`

Assuming that your `Personality` class looks something like

```
public Personailty {
   ....
}
```

then you will to add, so that it looks like

```
public Personailty {
   ....
   private Children1 obj1;

   public Children1 getObj1(){
      return this.obj1;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! however I am unsure of how to make the scope public I have attempted to make a getter for Children1 and return as obj1 but it doesn't work I think I am doing it wrong.

Comment: I have updated my answer for you.  Please also edit your question to show where the `Personality` code is e.g. Constructor, local method

Comment: *Children1 is an arraylist?*  **Children1 is a class, see your question**

Comment: Sorry my bad its late over here and I am tired. The code is updated I have commented the parts which sows errors.

Comment: Either you are extremely tired or you have bitten off more than you can chew, or my instructions are crap.  My edited code shows that you **need**  to add `Children1 obj1` as a class field and create a `getter` method.  If you can not do this you need to get some more basic help.

Comment: Thanks your way did work , I just have to convert an arraylist to a string now to get it showing in the chart..

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution below if you have attribute called obj1 in Personality class.

Personality Class should have:

```
private Children1 obj1;

public Children1 getObj1(){
    return this.obj1;
}
```

.

Change this your Code

```
ArrayList<Children1> c2 = c1.getChildren();
Children1 obj1 = c2.get(0);
```

to

```
ArrayList<Children1> c2 = c1.getChildren();
this.obj1 = c2.get(0);
```

And on your Chart class

```
DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
result.setValue("Value1",m.getObj1()); //attempted to get obj1 from Persoanlity Class
```